# как исправить эту ошибку при чтении файла?

Tags: python, utf-8

При попытке чтения файла вылезает такая ошибка:

```
se = f.readlines()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen codecs>", line 322, in decode
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xc5 in position 0: invalid continuation byte
```

Comment: [дубликаты](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=invalid+continuation+byte)

Comment: Указать правильную кодировку файла при чтении. Могу предположить, что у вас винда и кодировка cp1251.